# Consulta SQL que sume el STOCK de CodigoArticulo iguales

Tags: sql, vb.net

estoy realizando un sistema en VB.net donde tengo un datagridview (MultiSelect) con el registro de ventas de la empresa.
En otro datagridview muestro los articulos de la/s venta/s seleccionada/s en el primer DGV

```
"Select IdVenta, CodigoArticulo, Descripcion, Precio, Cantidad from Articulo_Venta WHERE " & ventas & " ORDER BY CodigoArticulo ASC"
```

La variable **Ventas** es una cadena de concatenaciones OR (Ej. IdVenta= 3 OR IdVenta=2 OR IdVenta=6) proveniente del siguiente codigo:

```
Dim ventas As String = String.Empty
Dim contador As Integer = 1
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In IdVenta
    If contador = IdVenta.Count Then
        ventas = ventas & "IdVenta = " & row.Cells("IdVenta").Value
    Else
        ventas = ventas & "IdVenta = " & row.Cells("IdVenta").Value & " OR "
        contador += 1
    End If
Next
```

Funciona todo perfecto pero en la consulta resultante se repiten **CodigoArticulo** y me muestra varias veces el mismo articulo (Vendidos en momentos diferentes o por diferentes vendedores), es decir:

> CodigoArticulo 1 | ... | Cantidad =3
>
> CodigoArticulo 4 | ... | Cantidad =2
>
> CodigoArticulo 1 | ... | Cantidad =6

y necesito que cuando hay mas de un CodigoArticulo repetido lo muestre una sola vez pero con sus cantidades sumadas

> CodigoArticulo 1 | ... | Cantidad =9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas usar Group By

```
SELECT IdVenta, CodigoArticulo, SUM(Cantidad) 'Cantidad', Descripcion, Precio 
FROM Articulo_Venta
WHERE " & ventas & " 
GROUP BY CodigoArticulo, IdVenta, Descripcion, Precio
ORDER BY CodigoArticulo ASC"
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. 
"Select IdVenta, CodigoArticulo, Descripcion, Precio, SUM(Cantidad) from Articulo_Venta WHERE " & ventas & " GROUP BY CodigoArticulo ORDER BY CodigoArticulo ASC" me devuelve el error: "Su consulta no incluye la expresion especificada IdVenta como parte de una funcion de agregado"

Comment: @Gonzalo Actuelize el código

Comment: WeaponX el precio no necesito sumarlo porque es el precio unitario. De todas formas sigue repitiendo los artículos y no les suma las cantidades. Como si no existiera el group by

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, el problema es que al incluir IdVenta dentro del GROUP BY no se agrupaban pq son Unicas. Pero ya esta! Gracias por todo

Comment: @Gonzalo Que bien.